# css style for :nth-child selector on class includes other elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

Hi smart people of stack, I have this completely unreasonable issue with :nth-child. Its not "locking" on to the specific class Im trying to attach it too.

In my first picture I had to make it skipp the first 3 excessive elements I want to skipp even though I've specified it to apply to the ".pageGrid" class. As you can see the first `<hr>`, then the `<div>`, then another `<hr>` have no class.

[image]

My second issue uses the same css as in another place and I had to add a invisible element because the :nth-child is again not applying to only the element I want to apply it on.

[image]

What am I missing?! Im really not getting this..

**Edit:**

Heres some code:

```
.wrapperProductList .prodListPage:nth-child(4n+1) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

The "+1" is to skipp the first  element..

```
.pageGrid:nth-child(3n+3) {
    margin-right: 0!important;
}
```

The "+3" here is to skipp the 3 first element that dont even have the .pageGrid class :(

```
<div class="clearfix wrapperProductList pageGrid">
<h1>Compact/Stackable</h1>
<a class="prodListPage" href="">
<a class="prodListPage" href="">
<a class="prodListPage" href="">
<a class="prodListPage" href="">
```

Belongs to this markup

Comment: Post some code please, I can't read those tiny images.

Comment: Ah sorry, I figured webdevelopers would know how to right click and "show image" ;) But ill post some code, hang on

Comment: @cammy it is the regular practice on stack to post code, straight from the "horse's mouth" so to speak, that way all of us can get right to the source of the issue and help you as fast as possible. Screenshots are generally a bit more difficult to deal with.

Comment: Fair enough, you're right!

Comment: @j08691 I have to take back my statement about you being right. I had to upload another picture on stack, and it doesn't specify a max width to uploaded content before it shrinks the size. >:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:nth-child()` doesn't "lock" onto class names or tag names the way you think it does. It only cares that the element [is the nth child of its parent together with *all* of its other siblings](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo), regardless of whether the other siblings are different elements or don't have specific classes, etc.

Having the +1 and +3 there is fine if you know you always want to skip the first element and first 3 elements respectively. That's just how `:nth-child()` works.

Comment: Really? I guess I've been foolish to think it worked that way, but when I come to think of its mostly used in tables and there you have the same sub elements ->  li's..

Comment: @Cammy: A lot of people run into the same problem. It's understandably not intuitive until you learn how it actually works.

Comment: I see, thanks for the input! :) Easy to solve by adding a wrapper anyways, even if its not optimal!

Comment: `nth-of-type` might be just a little more useful in this case, since it only checks against other elements of the same name. It still doesn't take class names into consideration, however.